# Is it possible to access an Ubuntu server on multiple networks?

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, webserver, ip

I hope someone can help. I have Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS running in VirtualBox, running as a web server on my laptop. I take my laptop between home and work, so the network configurations are different. It connects through WiFi and / or ethernet on each network, depending on any connectivity issues.  Since I use two networks, my computer often uses two IP addresses as the networks work in two different ranges.  This will cause me some minor conflicts on CMS sites that I am accessing, such as Wordpress.  This is due to the fact that, when I set up the site on one network, it uses the IP address that is assigned to the VM.  So, setting up a site from my work network, using 192.168.2.15 as my IP address, for example, will not translate to 192.168.0.6 on my home network.

Is there a way that I can overcome this, possibly with using the hostname?  I am a complete beginner to Ubuntu and I am using it because it was recommended to me by our IT manager, as a better alternative to WAMPServer and the like.  Even setting it up required a video tutorial to make sure I was doing it right.  Anything that you can give would be great.

**EDIT (08/12/2014)**

To summarize, so that it's clear:

I have `192.168.0.6` at home. I have `192.168.2.15` at work. I would like to use `http://uvm/` on both networks, since `uvm` is the hostname of my Ubuntu installation, and for `http://uvm/` to be able to connect whether at home or at work.

Comment: If **mdns** is supported then by simply doing **http://vum.local/** on any of the networks will connect to the respective **vum** device on the two networks.

Comment: quick and dirty but often useful enough is to add the hostname on one side to the /etc/hosts or /windows/system32/drivers/etc/lmhost.